# How to perform inner join in cnosdb？

Tags: cnosdb

data:

13.3MB

```
https://github.com/cnosdb/cnosdb/files/10083169/oceanic_station_20w.txt
\w oceanic_station_20w.txt
```

sql:
`SELECT * FROM air INNER JOIN sea ON sea.station = air.station;`

error:

```
error sending request for url (http://localhost:8902/api/v1/sql?tenant=cnosdb&db=public&chunked=false): connection closed before message completed
```

sys log:

```
[5270386.180177] Out of memory: Kill process 8211 (cnosdb) score 931 or sacrifice child
[5270386.180541] Killed process 8211 (cnosdb), UID 0, total-vm:52215152kB, anon-rss:15586780kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

Theoretically speaking, it is impossible to use 16G of memory to execute join on 13.3MB of data. Is there a problem with my system configuration, or is this a bug?